# choose array or fields with Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a object Person, who has many skills, each skill has a level (e.g. 0, 1, 2, ...), different Person has different skill sets, after each test, I will upsert many skills for specific person, e.g. for Tom, he have 3 skills currently:

```
skill1, level is 1
skill2, level is 2
skill3, level is 5
```

After a test, I want to upsert 4 skills for him:

```
skill1, level changes to 5
skill4, level is 3
skill5, level is 2
skill9, level is 3
```

the question is:
how can I design the document schema? one is modeling skill as field (identifier is unique in collection):

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("xxxx"),
  name: Tom,
  identifier: 12352352556,
  skill1: 1,
  skill2: 2,
  skill3: 5
}
```

another modeling is using embedded documents inside array:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("xxxx"),
  name: Tom,
  identifier: 12352352556,
  skills: [
    { name: "skill1", level: 1 },
    { name: "skill2", level: 2 },
    { name: "skill3", level: 5 }
  ]
}
```

In my application, each person can have as many as several hundred of skills, and each ***upsert*** (means some are updated, and some are inserted) may involve many skills change (sometimes less than one hundred, sometimes more than one hundred). just wondering which one is better.

Note: my mongodb is 3.6.x

Comment: Hello, I think you should consider creating a collection to store your skills.

Comment: @MickaëlB do you mean the option 1, modeling skills as fields of Document?

Comment: How are you using data?

Comment: @KevinSmith my use cases are: 1. Upsert skills for each person; 2. read the whole document for a specific person; 3. get all persons whose specific skill satisfy some condition like skill2 level >= 2, etc.